# Algebraic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I prove that $U=\{(x,y,z)|x\text{ is an integer}\}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I understand that I have to show $U$ is closed or not closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication but I'm unsure how I represent $x$ as an integer.

Thanks,
Angie

Answer (score 1):

Hint: to show it is not a subspace, you can show that it is not closed under scalar multiplication. To do this, you just need to find a vector $(x,y,z)$ with $x$ is an integer and multiply it by a real number so that the product's first coordinate is not an integer:

For example, if your vector has the form $(1,y,z)$, can you think of a real number $r$ such that the first coordinate of $r(1,y,z)=(r,r y,rz)$, which is $r$, is not an integer?

The point of this exercise is to emphasize that the scalars come from $\Bbb R$, and you can't guarantee that the product of a real number and a integer will always be an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was pretty obvious wasn't it? Ooops.

Could I ask you another question please? How do I interpret the following:
U={A|A^2=A, A is an element of M22} is not a subspace of M22.

I don't quite understand what it's asking in terms of A^2=A. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand the notation correctly, M22 is the space of $2\times 2$ matrices (the problem probably specifies where the entries come from), right? Then $U$ is the set of matrices that don't change when you square them ($A^2=A$ literally means that the matrix $A$ equals its square).

Comment: Yes U is the set of matrices that don't change when you square them. A = its square.

Comment: There is no other information in the question regarding where the entries come from. It just says show that it's not a subspace of M22. I need to learn how to use the formatting on this website sorry.

Comment: It's fine; for the formatting, check out this tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. For $U$, try to check whether $U$ is closed with respect to scalar multiplication and with respect to addition. One of them will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose A is a matrix in that set- $A^2= A$. Is that same property true of 3A?  Suppose A and B are two matrices in that set- $A^2= A$, $B^2= B$. Is that same property true of A+ B?